# Minify CSS class names with Angular CLI

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, minify

I'm looking for a way to improve performance by minifying my app's CSS class names. This approach is used by large websites and is also described [in this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/reducing-css-bundle-size-70-by-cutting-the-class-names-and-using-scope-isolation-625440de600b/).

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this with Angular CLI v10+ ? Ideally I'd want to add a webpack plugin while keeping the CLI for compilation, or a similar approach with minimal footprint, obviously for production builds only.

Comment: I believe this question does not deserve to be closed, I have also been looking for a way to do this for a while now too... +1

Comment: It'd be constructive to know the reason of why people ask for it to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something using the [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) API. By default it uses `Emulated` which generate large CSS class names. If you change that in your components to `ShadowDom`. This will encapsulate the styles and will shift everything to use Shadow DOM. With Shadow DOM the styles won't be leaked outside the components. You have to test it though and check for browsers support because it's not supported everywhere. Also, global styles might not work as you expect.

Edit: I also found this [interesting article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1294/angular-css-modules) that explain something similar using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

[Breezify](https://github.com/glebgorokhov/breezify) does exactly what you need.

Installation and usage are pretty simple:

- `npm i -d breezify`
- `breezify init`

Then the config file will be created, make sure `files.buildDir` and `files.outputDir` are exactly what you want, then integrate `breezify do` into your build command like that:

```json
// package.json
// Replace this:
{
  scripts: {
    build: "ng build"
  }
}

// With this:
{
  scripts: {
    build: "ng build && breezify do"
  }
}
```

Then just build your project as you usually do.